I am having trouble with my Unity Android Gradle
So, I have been trying to use Google Admob recently with firebase plugins (Storage, Firestore, Auth, Messaging). So far, I am using the latest Firebase SDK versions(11.9.0) and Google Mobile Ads(9.1.0).
I am using custom main manifest, custom main gradle template, custom base gradle template, custom gradle properties template and custom gradle settings template.
settings.gradle
settings
Console Logs Using Version (6.7.1)
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

Where:
  `Settings file  'D:\\Projects\\DriversHub\\Library\\Bee\\Android\\Prj\\IL2CPP\\Gradle\\settings.gradle' line: 16`

What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating settings 'Gradle'.

Could not find method dependencyResolutionManagement() for arguments \[settings_eefuektiwehz85h33iqhdm3f6$\_run_closure1@29080365\] on settings 'Gradle' of type org.gradle.initialization.DefaultSettings.

Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get                          more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)

I have tried solving it by downloading gradle versions on their official websites. I tried using the latest version(8.7) and the recommended version on the official google ads docs(6.7.1) but nothing has worked so far and I cant build an apk since then.

Do you know what your AGP (Android Gradle Plugin) version is?

Have you made sure your Unity editor is set to use the Gradle instance you installed?
Also what are the results from trying the troubleshooting guide?
